# Stretch items to fill page with CSS print layout

Tags: html, css, layout, printing

I am designing a quiz using HTML/CSS. It is meant to be printed on paper.

It currently looks like this:
[image: Paginated quiz]

Originally, the question boxes were being split in half at the page break, but I managed to avoid that with

```
.questionBox {
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Now, I have a more ambitious goal: **I want to avoid wasting space at the bottom of each page by stretching each question box out so they're all taller.** This should be done dynamically, sort of analogous to how flexbox stretches elements horizontally to fill the space with flex-grow.

I made a few attempts using flexbox and `flex-direction: column`, but no luck so far. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the height property to stretch the .questionBox div to full height.

```
.questionBox {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

height: 100vh = 100% of the viewport height.